# Al Heredar botones desde un Formulario y cerrar y abrir el mismo los botones no se quedan en su lugar

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Mi problema es justamente que la herencia de los formularios, al abrir, cerrar o compilar el formulario hijo los botones se comportan como si tuvieran vida propia, se mueven de lugar

Aquí adjunto un enlace para ver que me pasa, se que poner enlaces es una mala practica, pero necesito explicar mi problema lo mejor posible

https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApYO6DZzi_l-8zp-Fvr4nFkgta5J?e=d482SE

Esta es la información para un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible, yo uso DevExpress, ojala no sea un problema

**Formulario Padre**

```
public partial class BaseMantenimiento1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public BaseMantenimiento1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void Nuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Guardar.Enabled = true;
Cancelar.Enabled = true;
Editar.Enabled = false;
Buscar.Enabled = false;
Nuevo.Enabled = false;

}

public void Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Nuevo.Enabled = true;
Guardar.Enabled = false;
Cancelar.Enabled = false;
Buscar.Enabled = true;
Editar.Enabled = true;

}

private void Cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Guardar.Enabled = false;
Cancelar.Enabled = false;
Nuevo.Enabled = true;
Editar.Enabled = true;
Buscar.Enabled = true;
}

private void Editar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Nuevo.Enabled = false;
Buscar.Enabled = false;
Editar.Enabled = false;
Guardar.Enabled = true;
Cancelar.Enabled = true;
}
```

**Formulario Hijo**

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseMantenimiento1
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: No te preocupes, lo que está mal es depender únicamente de un enlace.  Si puedes explicar la publicación y acompañarla de enlaces si lo crees necesario.

Comment: @Mateo Gracias , ahi edite el post y puse una breve explicacion, por favor verifica si puedes ayudarme a solucionar mi problema